# Find children containing Class and add extra class

Tags: jquery

I'm triying to add a class to a child but only on children containing a specific class

This is an example of the existing HTML:

```
    <div class="iteration-Odd">
     <div class="style1"></div>
     <div class="style2"></div>
    </div>
```

And I need to add an additional class to the div with "style2"

Tried this with no luck:

```
$('.iteration-Odd').find('.style2').addClass('.new-class');
```

Comment: `iteration-odd` is not equal to `iteration-Odd`

Comment: Correct, it was a mistake while typing the example, didn't want to share the real code since is too long and unnecesary.

Comment: `$('.iteration-Odd .style2').addClass('.new-class');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `addClass` takes the className i.e. `new-class` not `.new-class`
> `iteration-odd` is className not `iteration-Odd`

```js
$('.iteration-odd').find('.style2').addClass('new-class');
```

```css
div {
  height: 1rem;
  background: wheat;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.new-class {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="iteration-odd">
  <div class="style1"></div>
  <div class="style2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this,

you need to replace `O` to `o`

```js
$('.iteration-odd').find('.style2').addClass('new-class');
```

```css
.new-class{
  color:green;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="iteration-odd">
     <div class="style1">1</div>
     <div class="style2">2</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It was my mistake while writing the question, the actual code match.

Comment: No worries, if you are stuck in existing code please share with us. We will check and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can do with `Parent Child` `jquery selector` like `.iteration-odd > .style2` here you don't need to use `find` method

For More detail check this link -> [Click Me](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_parent_child.asp)

```js
$('.iteration-odd > .style2').addClass('new-class');
```

```css
.new-class{
  color:white;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="iteration-odd">
   <div class="style1">1</div>
   <div class="style2">2</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.iteration-odd div:nth-child(2)').addClass('new-class');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.